# How to convert video format on cloud based application

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, video-encoding

I'm building a smartphone application which supposed also to take a short video and send it to a cloud-based-storage like the Amazon S3. I also have servers on the cloud (i.e. on EC2).

Let's say I resize the video file on the app (like WhatsApp does). I want it to be delivered to other users, with other devices (both cellular and desktops), so I guess I need to convert the video to other formats.

Using the Amazon Elastic Transcoder seems very expensive (about $0.015 per video minute) cause I plan to have a lot of video files stored on it.

What should I do? Use a format-conversion program on my servers (which also on the cloud)?

I don't want to stream the videos, but to give the files like in  whatsApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is less about supporting multiple formats (MP4 is more or less supported everywhere now), but instead multiple bitrates/resolutions. Also having multiple bitrates allows you to take advantage of adaptive streaming.

There are 3 parts to the system you need to consider:

1. Conversion
2. Storage
3. Delivery

**Conversion**
Video conversion is CPU intensive enough that you want to convert the videos once and store the result. Pick 3-6 bitrates/resolutions that will cover your application needs and convert all videos you receive into these formats.

You can use Elastic Transcorder, Zencoder, or role your own. Rolling your own will definitely be complex to scale. You need to built it as a job queue type system running multiple instances to handle the conversion work.

**Storage**
After conversion you need to store your files. If you are using AWS products, this is where S3 will come into play.

**Delivery**
If you get a lot of traffic, this is likely to be the most costly aspect of your project. Taking advantage of streaming can reduce costs somewhat, since you don't need to download the entire file. Cloudfront supports direct download or streaming using S3 or other source as the origin.

Comment: Hi @datasage, thanks for the detailed answer. I think I'll try the Zencoder, although it seems a bit expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out this tutorial on cloud-based transcoding of adaptive streaming content (MPEG-DASH, HLS) and how to deploy it on S3/CloudFront: http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/